# C issue with function returning a character array

Tags: c, arrays, function, debugging, character

This is one function in the header file for an assignment I'm working on.

```
#ifndef CARDGAMES_H
#define CARDGAMES_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char suit;
    char label;
    int value;
} card ;

//function prototypes (removed the majority of them, this is just a segment of header file)

void addToDeck(card deck[], card toAdd, int * deckLength);
void printDeck(card deck[], int deckLength);

card removeCard(card deck[], int * deckLength, int index);


*/
card removeCard(card deck[], int * deckLength, int index){
        card removed = deck[index];
        int x = *deckLength;
        deck[index] = deck[x];
        deck[x] = removed;
        x=x-1;
        *deckLength = x;
        return removed;
```

Below is the part of the driver I am testing this function with... where my issue arises.

```
printf("\tThe deck after adding the ten of hearts: \n");
    printDeck(deck, ncards);

        printf("Testing removeCard.\n");

    removeCard(deck, &ncards, 0);
    printf("\tThe deck after removing the first card: ");
    printDeck(deck, ncards);
```

Below is my output after running the complied program:

```
     The deck after adding the ten of hearts: 
King of hearts
King of spades
King of diamonds
Queen of diamonds
ten of hearts
Testing removeCard.
    The deck after removing the first card: ten �?D
King of spades
King of diamonds
Queen of diamonds
```

This is doing just as I want it to do. However the ten of hearts is not printing properly. It has �?D in it? Could anyone explain where I went wrong here?

Comment: change `int x = *deckLength;` to `int x = *deckLength - 1;` and `*deckLength = x;` to `*deckLength = *deckLength - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

In C arrays starts from 0, so

```
    int x = *deckLength;
    deck[index] = deck[x];
```

is wrong. The last element of array has `arraySize - 1` index.

The correct code should be

```
card removeCard(card deck[], int * deckLength, int index){
        card removed = deck[index];
        int indexLast = *deckLength - 1;
        deck[index] = deck[indexLast];
        deck[indexLast] = removed;
        *deckLength -= 1;
        return removed;
```

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. I appreciate it